# Acceder a una variable de un objeto que esta dentro de un arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, ordenamiento

tengo un arraylist creado que dentro de el tiene los mismos tipos de objetos {participante(String nombre, int puntos, String tiempo). Bien, ahora queria ordenar el array segun el int puntos de cada objeto. He probado con el metodo sort de List pero no accedo bien a la variable de el objeto que esta dentro o no se si se puede de la manera que yo lo hago. Mi codigo seria el siguiente:

```
    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++) {
        participantes.add(a, pat.introducir(sc));

    }
    for( int x=0;x<participantes.size();x++){
        participantes.sort(participantes.get(x).puntos);
    }`
```

Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda ofrecida!

Comment: Implementa la interface `Comparable` en la clase `Participante`, y si lo haces bien, luego de hacer el sort la lista quedará ordenada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres ordenar los items mediante `Collections.sort()` debes hacer que `Participante` implemente la interfaz `Comparable` como te lo sugirió Glenn Sandoval.

Para hacer eso simplemente pasa de:

```
class Participante
```

a

```
class Participante implements Comparable<Participante>
```

y sobreescribe el método `compareTo()`, teniendo en cuenta que puntos es `private` y has definido un Getter llamado `getPuntos()`, de una manera como la siguiente:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Participante p2) {
    int puntosDelOtro = p2.getPuntos();

    // Orden ascendente (menor a mayor)
    return this.puntos - puntosDelOtro ;

    // Orden descendente (mayor a menor)
    //return puntosDelOtro - this.puntos;
}
```

Luego solo debes llamar a `Collections.sort()` pasándole como parámetro el `ArrayList` que quieres ordenar y listo.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Lo único es que aconsejaría que siguieses el estándar en cuanto a la nomenclatura de los metodos Getter y Setter.

Comment: Pensé en escribirlo así por pedagogía, para que alex entienda mejor, pero, aún así sugieres que lo cambie?

Comment: Si, aunque en cualquier caso está bien tu respuesta.

Comment: No necesitas hacer un casteo aquí: `((Participante)p2).obtenerPuntos()`, porque `p2` ya es de tipo `Participante`. A excepción que el tipo de `p2` sea `Object`, pues ahí si se necesita el casting. Sin embargo, lo ideal sería usar la interfaz genérica (`Comparable<E>`).

Comment: Usando este metodo que tu me dices, no me deja cambiar el Object o a Participante p2 tal y como tu tienes, no lo detecta como metodo que hay que sobreescribir y me pide otro

Comment: @alexnuñezperez Debes de implementar la interfaz Comparable como genérica. Ejemplo: `class Participante implements Comparable<Participante>`. De de este modo, no dará error de compilación, ya que al momento de sobrescribir el método `compareTo` estarías cumpliendo con la firma de la rutina (la que especifique `Comparable<E>`).

Comment: Me di cuenta justo después de escribirlo, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Si estas utilizando Java 8 puedes hacer uso de los streams

```
List<Participante> sortedList = participantes.stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Participante::getPuntos))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

o

```
List<Participante> sortedList = participantes.stream()
.sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.getPuntos() - o2.getPuntos())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Sino, como te han dicho en los comentarios, implementa la interfaz Comparable

Answer (score 0):

El método sort necesita de la interfaz comparable, la cual te obliga a construir un método llamado comparteTo que devuelve un número int

Este método obligado a construir recibe 1 objeto. De forma que se utiliza: objeto1.compareTo(objeto2) devolviendo un -1 si objeto1.valor< objeto2.valor, devuelve 1 si objeto1.valor>objeto2.valor y 0 si objeto1.valor=objeto2.valor según el valor que quieras utilizar dentro de ese objeto (el método lo programas tú, asi que puedes elegir el valor que quieras pero ha de devolver esos valores (en realidad puede devolver cualquier negativo, cero o cualquier positivo)

Cuando tengas ese método construido, el sort te funcionará.

Por otra parte, las variables de las clases normalmente deberían de estar encapsuladas, para no poder acceder a ellas mediante objeto.variable, y no poder hacer objeto.variable=nuevoValor. Normalmente las variables de los objetos deben de llevar sus getter y setter según se necesiten leer, o escribir en ellas.

Si tienes un objeto linterna, no debes de poder acceder a los cables para conectarlos (variable booleana conectado=true), sino que debes de usar el método interruptor, el ya internamente si accede a los cables, pero la persona que tiene la linterna no accede a ellos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion!!