# ¿Cómo ordenar un arreglo por uno de sus atributos solamente? JAVA

Tags: java, array, poo

Tengo un catalogo de autos y estos cuentan con diferentes especificaciones, entre esos serie, año, marca, modelo etcétera.

Debo buscar dentro de este catalogo a un auto por serie, y después debe mostrarlos ordenados por orden de serie. Al intentar copiar el codigo de ordenamiento me marca un error que dice que la linea requiere variable y encontró valor

`autos[j+1].getSerie()= autos[j].getSerie());`

lo mismo con la siguiente

```
autos[j+1].getSerie()=aux;
```

la clase Auto tiene estos atributos

```
Auto {
    private int serie,año;
    private String marca, modelo,color,motor,status;
    private double precioDeLista;
CatalogoAutos autos[];}
```

La clase CatalogoAutos es así

```
public class CatalogoAutos{

    Auto autos[] = new Auto[1];
    CatalogoAutos(){

    }
```

y personal autorizado que es el que puede ordenar por serie, en el método de ordenar por inseccion lo estoy poniendo así  pero me marca error, no sé cómo podría hacer que solo maneje las series
el error es unexpected type required: variable found : value en la parte
 `de autos[j+1].getSerie()= autos[j].getSerie());`

```
public class PersonalAutorizado extends CatalogoAutos {
public void insercionDirecta(int Autos[]){
for(int i=1; i < autos.length;i++){
int aux = autos[i].getSerie();
int j = i -1;
while((j>=0) && (aux<autos[j].getSerie())){
autos[j+1].getSerie()= autos[j].getSerie());
j--;
}
autos[j+1].getSerie()=aux;
}
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Qué error te marca? Por favor incluye el mensaje de error completo. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio. 
También revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola. No se puede igualar el resultado de una función por otra... en dado caso, si quieres cambiar el valor del atributo, en los atributos privados necesitas tener métodos set que ajusten el valor del atributo ( `autos[j+1].setSerie(autos[j].getSerie())` ) o en otro caso hacer el atributo publico y ajustarlo directamente ( `autos[j+1].serie = autos[j].getSerie()` )

Comment: Posible duplicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/351741/169744

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

No tiene por que ser complicado.

```
void sortCarsBySerie(){
    Arrays.sort(autos, (auto1, auto2)->Integer.compare(auto1.getSerie(), auto2.getSerie()));
}
```

Aqui usamos el metodo sort con [dos parametros](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)), siendo el primero el arreglo que quieres ordenar y el segundo el criterio compadaror.

Respecto al comparador usamos una lambda que es una simplificacion de codigo para poner una funcion simple.
Como no queremos poner como comparar los campos de serie reusamos el criterio de comparacion que ya tiene la clase `Integer`, y le pasamos los valores de serie de ambos autos delegandole la comparacion.

Un ejemplo de corrida seria:

> Autos sin ordenar
>
> [Auto(serie=42886, año=1993, marca=Von LLC, modelo=Wilma Leggrowbach, color=black, motor=Warhol, status=Movies & Tools, precioDeLista=11964.71), Auto(serie=4585, año=2043, marca=Jacobs Group, modelo=Claire DeAir, color=tan, motor=Rubens, status=Outdoors, precioDeLista=56235.06), Auto(serie=54594, año=1974, marca=Fahey-Cronin, modelo=Ricky T. Ladder, color=grey, motor=Monet, status=Jewelry, precioDeLista=27560.29), Auto(serie=24412, año=1973, marca=Lowe-Williamson, modelo=Sue Yu, color=teal, motor=Seurat, status=Music, precioDeLista=28501.85), Auto(serie=88692, año=2005, marca=Hauck-Kassulke, modelo=Sue Ridge, color=violet, motor=Seurat, status=Jewelry, precioDeLista=67352.44), Auto(serie=89442, año=1976, marca=Grady-Wisozk, modelo=Rita Booke, color=blue, motor=Renoir, status=Books, precioDeLista=78644.78), Auto(serie=53830, año=1977, marca=Schaefer, Stokes and Moore, modelo=Dinah Soares, color=white, motor=Gauguin, status=Baby, Health & Home, precioDeLista=45959.66), Auto(serie=50990, año=1929, marca=Kunde, VonRueden and O'Keefe, modelo=Rhoda Mule, color=mint green, motor=Vettriano, status=Clothing, Computers & Tools, precioDeLista=40329.04), Auto(serie=16449, año=2036, marca=Hirthe, Hilll and Legros, modelo=Lynn O. Liam, color=orange, motor=Vettriano, status=Baby, precioDeLista=82767.81), Auto(serie=39437, año=1962, marca=Mayert, Hackett and Yost, modelo=Zoltan Pepper, color=gold, motor=Botticelli, status=Books, precioDeLista=80584.68)]
>
> Autos ordenados
>
> [Auto(serie=4585, año=2043, marca=Jacobs Group, modelo=Claire DeAir, color=tan, motor=Rubens, status=Outdoors, precioDeLista=56235.06), Auto(serie=16449, año=2036, marca=Hirthe, Hilll and Legros, modelo=Lynn O. Liam, color=orange, motor=Vettriano, status=Baby, precioDeLista=82767.81), Auto(serie=24412, año=1973, marca=Lowe-Williamson, modelo=Sue Yu, color=teal, motor=Seurat, status=Music, precioDeLista=28501.85), Auto(serie=39437, año=1962, marca=Mayert, Hackett and Yost, modelo=Zoltan Pepper, color=gold, motor=Botticelli, status=Books, precioDeLista=80584.68), Auto(serie=42886, año=1993, marca=Von LLC, modelo=Wilma Leggrowbach, color=black, motor=Warhol, status=Movies & Tools, precioDeLista=11964.71), Auto(serie=50990, año=1929, marca=Kunde, VonRueden and O'Keefe, modelo=Rhoda Mule, color=mint green, motor=Vettriano, status=Clothing, Computers & Tools, precioDeLista=40329.04), Auto(serie=53830, año=1977, marca=Schaefer, Stokes and Moore, modelo=Dinah Soares, color=white, motor=Gauguin, status=Baby, Health & Home, precioDeLista=45959.66), Auto(serie=54594, año=1974, marca=Fahey-Cronin, modelo=Ricky T. Ladder, color=grey, motor=Monet, status=Jewelry, precioDeLista=27560.29), Auto(serie=88692, año=2005, marca=Hauck-Kassulke, modelo=Sue Ridge, color=violet, motor=Seurat, status=Jewelry, precioDeLista=67352.44), Auto(serie=89442, año=1976, marca=Grady-Wisozk, modelo=Rita Booke, color=blue, motor=Renoir, status=Books, precioDeLista=78644.78)]

Comment: muchas gracias, disculpa y sabes cómo podría hacerle para que solo aparezcan los que coinciden en marca y año? He estado intentando con un .stream pero creo funciona diferente?

Comment: efectivamente. No deberia ser un problema el funcionamiento interno de stream. Espero haber resuelto tu pregunta sobre el ordenamiento.